# Background image for button not working in jQuery mobile?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, background-image

I want to set background image of the button for following image:

[image: cancel]

using this code:

```
 <style>
 .cancel-button {background-image:url(images/cancelbutton.png) !important;}
 </style>

 <a href="index.html" data-role="button" cancel="cancel-button"></a>
```

but I got the output of the button like following image

[image: output]

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Fixed solution

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/AJsTR/

### CSS:

```
.cancel-button {
    background-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XDDb.png") !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    border-width: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 transparent !important;
    width: 197px !important;
    height: 75px !important;
}
```

## Responsive solution

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/AJsTR/1/

```
.cancel-button {
    background-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XDDb.png") !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    border-width: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 transparent !important;
    background-size: 100% 100% !important;
}
```

## Final note

Take a look at this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/learn-how-to-customize-jquery-mobile-application/)** if you want to find out how to customize jQuery Mobile elements by yourself.

Comment: how to do this concept for inline buttons

Comment: Do you want same image or different ones?

Comment: I want a diffrent images

Comment: OK, give me few minutes.

Comment: Ok.Sure I am waiting for your valuable answer

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/AJsTR/3/ just change .button-2 and .button-3 images. This examples have 3 button in the row, if you want more/less just change: width: 33% !important;

Comment: Follow your steps i got the output like this http://jsfiddle.net/techpalani/ntsXb/

Comment: My solution will work only with buttons create from an a tag. It will not work on a input tag. Replace your input button with an a tag button and trigger submit through javascript.